# Java : Pattern How to match any character or symbol in any order between the two braces

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match any character symbols in any order able to

I have three lines all combine in one line

```
line 1 = DE-120  LLL[310]  CHR(9049         9360          TRANSNSW      400000000000000018416)

line2 =  DE-121  LLL[035]  CHR(00317010024/VER/1//CRT/UCAF//POS/2/)


line3 =  DE-123  LLL[151] (/VER/1//MSO/SYSTEST_MSO_DASH//TXD/2020-04-20T03:47:47.492Z//AQU/SYSTEST_ACQ_S2I//TTY/AUTH//OID/311e12cc-4561-4b0a-9540-f30d5ef8d744//CLI/IUV5OJDNV5LZG/)";
```

so far my code is

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


Pattern patternreq = Pattern.compile("(DE\\W*\\d*)(\\s*\\w*\\W*)(\\d*)(\\W*\\s*)(\\w*)(\\()([\\w*\\s*]+)(\\))");

String txn = "DE-120  LLL[310]  CHR(9049                                                 9252                                                    9360                                                            9408000000009556SYSTEST_MSO_DASH                        TRANSNSW        9661293208721                               400000000000000018416)DE-121  LLL[035]  CHR(00317010024/VER/1//CRT/UCAF//POS/2/)DE-123  LLL[151]  CHR(/VER/1//MSO/SYSTEST_MSO_DASH//TXD/2020-04-20T03:47:47.492Z//AQU/SYSTEST_ACQ_S2I//TTY/AUTH//OID/311e12cc-4561-4b0a-9540-f30d5ef8d744//CLI/IUV5OJDNV5LZG/)";

Matcher m = patternreq.matcher(txn);

   String field = matcher_request.group(1);
   String length = matcher_request.group(3);
   String value = matcher_request.group(7);
```

I am able to match the first line which is DE-120 and extract the values from the group which I need 
but not able to do the second and third line.

how can I match all the characters symbols between the two braces of CHR(.....) as these values can be of any order and in any pattern,tried few patterns like .*? those didn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: A lot of parts in your pattern are optional, but it does not match the other strings as the character class at the end does not contain all the characters to match. See https://regex101.com/r/cr8tHt/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex: `(DE\S*)[^[]*\[([^\]]*)\][^(]*\(([^)]*)\)`

The 3 values you want are in groups 1, 2, and 3.

*Explanation:*

```
(DE\S*)     Capture text starting with `DE` and up to whitespace
[^[]*\[     Skip up to and including `[`
([^\]]*)    Capture everything up to and excluding `]`
\]          Skip `]`, must be present
[^(]*\(     Skip up to and including `(`
([^)]*)     Capture everything up to and excluding `)`
\)          Skip `)`, must be present
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XKRzGa/1) for demo.